# Webpage does not respond after clicking manage button on IBM Cloud Db2

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

Can't open the web page which has the 'Open console' button after clicking the manage button on IBM Cloud Db2. It shows that the response time of the webpage is too long. By the way, I already tried to use firefox, chrome, ie and 360 to open the webpage, but all failed.

Comment: Is this for the free lite plan of Db2 on Cloud and the us-south region? See other Stack Overflow questions...

Comment: Operational issues for commercial cloud services (IBM Db2 on cloud) are outside of the programming remit for stackoverflow.  Open a ticket with IBM support if you are a paying customer. If you are a "free" customer (Db2 lite plan), delete your service and recreate in a different datacentre and retry.